# JavaFx Animation Following Dynamic Path

Tags: java, javafx

I have an ArrayList, where each particle's x and y position are changing with time.

I want to animate it's trajectory using JavaFx. I have tried using Timeline among other things, and it seems to work okay if I specify a start and end location for a particle. However, I'd like the particle to follow a path which changes with time. I'm thinking a solution is perhaps to make an array of KeyValues, which is first filled by running the particle's trajectory. And then timeline animate these KeyValues. Will this work? Also, is there a cleaner solution - I'm sure there is, but can't find anything! I'd appreciate any guidance, I'm a Java Newbie :)

```
// returns time elapsed since start of program  
public double getTime(){
    return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0;
}   

public startButton(){

    // defining origin
    DoubleProperty x  = new SimpleDoubleProperty(250);
    DoubleProperty y  = new SimpleDoubleProperty(150);

    // generate array of KeyValue for ONE particle in fireworks 
    do { 
    fireworks = manager.getFireworks(getTime());    // fireworks is an ArrayList<Particle>, getFireworks is updated based on time input.
    double[] pos = fireworks.get(0).getPosition();  // gets the first Particle's position

    // generate KeyValue Array (is this possible?) containing 
    // KeyValue(x, pos[0]), KeyValue(x, pos[0 + dt].... etc...
    // basically a trajectory for the particle while it's alive

    } while (fireworks.get(0).isAlive(getTime()));

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10),           
                      //...insert KeyValue array here....//
    // add KeyFrame to timeline
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            drawLaunchTube();
            gc.setFill(Color.FORESTGREEN);
            gc.fillOval(x.doubleValue(), y.doubleValue(), 10, 10);
        }
    };
    timer.start();
    timeline.play();
}
```

Comment: Probably the simpler solution is to animate the particle in the animation timer, instead of in the timeline.

Comment: There is a [fireworks sample in Ensemble](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/tip/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/graphics2d/canvas), perhaps you should study that.  The full Ensemble application including the Fireworks Sample is [downloadable in the JDK 8 Demos and Samples package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: @James_D I've tried to animate it in the animation timer, and it's a little better I think. I'll keep trying thx.

Comment: @jewelsea I'll take a look, thx.